# Подскажите как рассположить елементы в ряд, в мобильной версии?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, scss

Мне нужно чтобы навигация занимала всю страницу при ширине екрана 600px, сейчас мой код выглядит вот так

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  html,
  body {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #555;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  .header {
    color: white;
    background: linear-gradient(60deg, red, orange);
    text-align: center;
    flex-shrink: 1;
  }
  
  .main {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  
  .footer {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5em;
  }
  
  .section {
    width: 60%;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .section__header {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5vw;
  }
  
  .navigation {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 0.5em;
  }
  .nav-list-item {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #808080;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    color: white;
  }
  
  .nav-list-link {
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .nav-list {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .css-units {
    color: #8b0000;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.125em;
  }
  .units-list {
    height: 1.75em;
    line-height: 1.75em;
  
  }
  
  .news {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 0.5em;
  }
  picture{
      width: 60%;
  }
img{
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}  
@media screen and (min-width: 600px){
  .navigation {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .section {
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .news {
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.css"
      integrity="sha256-WAgYcAck1C1/zEl5sBl5cfyhxtLgKGdpI3oKyJffVRI="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <h1>Responsive website</h1>
    </header>
    <main class="main">
      <nav class="navigation">
        <ul class="nav-list">
          <li class="nav-list-item"><a class="nav-list-link" href="#">Responsive images</a></li>
          <li class="nav-list-item"><a class="nav-list-link" href="#">Mediaqueries</a></li>
          <li class="nav-list-item"><a class="nav-list-link" href="#">Flexbox</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <section class="section">
        <h2 class="section__header">True story</h2>
        <picture> 
         <source class="big-picture" srcset="https://gromcode.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/front-end/html-css/lesson22/hw2/big.png"
          media="(min-width: 1200px)">
         <img class="smal-picture" src="https://gromcode.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/front-end/html-css/lesson22/hw2/small.png"
         alt="smal picture"> 
         <!-- <img class="big-picture" srcset="https://gromcode.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/front-end/html-css/lesson22/hw2/big.png" 
         alt="picture">  -->
     </picture>
        <p>There are few ways to define <code>font-size</code>:</p>
        <ul class="units-list">
          <li>
            <span class="css-units">px</span> are good if you need strict definition for a size of
            text. In other cases it is better to use relative units listed below.
          </li>
          <li><span class="css-units">em</span> based on current font size</li>
          <li><span class="css-units">rem</span> based on <code>&lt;html&gt;</code> font-size</li>
          <li><span class="css-units">%</span> based on parent font size</li>
          <li><span class="css-units">vh</span> (viewport height) based on screen height</li>
          <li><span class="css-units">vw</span> (viewport width) based on screen width</li>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <aside class="news">
        <h2>Not a news</h2>
        <p>A web page should look good on any device!</p>
      </aside>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer">Welcome to the responsive world!</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Расскажите более подробно, что у вас не получилось и что вы уже пытались сделать, каков текущий результат. Пожалуйста, старайтесь писать более развернутые вопрос, тогда вам смогут помочь более оперативно и качественно.

Comment: мне нужно сделать адаптивный сайт под мобильную версию, задала стили для @media screen, но не понимаю почему при сужении екрана у меня елементы не выстраиваються в колонку.

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  html,
  body {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #555;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  .header {
    color: white;
    background: linear-gradient(60deg, red, orange);
    text-align: center;
    flex-shrink: 1;
  }
  
  .main {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .footer {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5em;
  }
  
  .section {
    flex-direction: column;
    /* width: 60%; */
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .section__header {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5vw;
  }
  
  .navigation {
    width: 100%;
   /* width: 20%; */
    padding: 0.5em;
  }
  .nav-list-item {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #808080;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    color: white;
  }
  
  .nav-list-link {
    /* width: 100%; */
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .nav-list {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .css-units {
    color: #8b0000;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.125em;
  }
  .units-list {
    height: 1.75em;
    line-height: 1.75em;
  }
  .news {
    width: 20%;
    /* width: 20%; */
    padding: 0.5em;
    width: 100%;
  }
  picture{
      width: 60%;
  }
img{
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}  
@media screen and (min-width: 600px){
  .navigation{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .section{
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.css"
      integrity="sha256-WAgYcAck1C1/zEl5sBl5cfyhxtLgKGdpI3oKyJffVRI="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <h1>Responsive website</h1>
    </header>
    <main class="main">
      <nav class="navigation">
        <ul class="nav-list">
          <li class="nav-list-item"><a class="nav-list-link" href="#">Responsive images</a></li>
          <li class="nav-list-item"><a class="nav-list-link" href="#">Mediaqueries</a></li>
          <li class="nav-list-item"><a class="nav-list-link" href="#">Flexbox</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <section class="section">
        <h2 class="section__header">True story</h2>
        <picture> 
         <source class="big-picture" srcset="https://gromcode.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/front-end/html-css/lesson22/hw2/big.png"
          media="(min-width: 1200px)">
         <img class="smal-picture" src="https://gromcode.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/front-end/html-css/lesson22/hw2/small.png"
         alt="smal picture"> 
         <!-- <img class="big-picture" srcset="https://gromcode.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/front-end/html-css/lesson22/hw2/big.png" 
         alt="picture">  -->
     </picture>
        <p>There are few ways to define <code>font-size</code>:</p>
        <ul class="units-list">
          <li>
            <span class="css-units">px</span> are good if you need strict definition for a size of
            text. In other cases it is better to use relative units listed below.
          </li>
          <li><span class="css-units">em</span> based on current font size</li>
          <li><span class="css-units">rem</span> based on <code>&lt;html&gt;</code> font-size</li>
          <li><span class="css-units">%</span> based on parent font size</li>
          <li><span class="css-units">vh</span> (viewport height) based on screen height</li>
          <li><span class="css-units">vw</span> (viewport width) based on screen width</li>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <aside class="news">
        <h2>Not a news</h2>
        <p>A web page should look good on any device!</p>
      </aside>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer">Welcome to the responsive world!</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

**текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом**

Comment: Вот что получилось, только текст налазит на другой и вроде как с футером проблема подскажите как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Ставим `.main {flex-direction: column;}` это правило выстроит блоки в колонки, далее растягиваем naw, section, news {width: 100%;} и убираем у .units-list высоту

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  html,
  body {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #555;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  .header {
    color: white;
    background: linear-gradient(60deg, red, orange);
    text-align: center;
    flex-shrink: 1;
  }
  
  .main {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .footer {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5em;
  }
  
  .section {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .section__header {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5vw;
  }
  
  .navigation {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5em;
  }
  .nav-list-item {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #808080;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    color: white;
  }
  
  .nav-list-link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .nav-list {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .css-units {
    color: #8b0000;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.125em;
  }
  .units-list {
    /* height: 1.75em; */
    line-height: 1.75em;
  }
  .news {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 0.5em;
    width: 100%;
  }
  picture{
      width: 60%;
  }
img{
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}  
@media screen and (min-width: 600px){
  .navigation{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .section{
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.css"
      integrity="sha256-WAgYcAck1C1/zEl5sBl5cfyhxtLgKGdpI3oKyJffVRI="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <h1>Responsive website</h1>
    </header>
    <main class="main">
      <nav class="navigation">
        <ul class="nav-list">
          <li class="nav-list-item"><a class="nav-list-link" href="#">Responsive images</a></li>
          <li class="nav-list-item"><a class="nav-list-link" href="#">Mediaqueries</a></li>
          <li class="nav-list-item"><a class="nav-list-link" href="#">Flexbox</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <section class="section">
        <h2 class="section__header">True story</h2>
        <picture> 
         <source class="big-picture" srcset="https://gromcode.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/front-end/html-css/lesson22/hw2/big.png"
          media="(min-width: 1200px)">
         <img class="smal-picture" src="https://gromcode.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/front-end/html-css/lesson22/hw2/small.png"
         alt="smal picture"> 
         <!-- <img class="big-picture" srcset="https://gromcode.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/front-end/html-css/lesson22/hw2/big.png" 
         alt="picture">  -->
     </picture>
        <p>There are few ways to define <code>font-size</code>:</p>
        <ul class="units-list">
          <li>
            <span class="css-units">px</span> are good if you need strict definition for a size of
            text. In other cases it is better to use relative units listed below.
          </li>
          <li><span class="css-units">em</span> based on current font size</li>
          <li><span class="css-units">rem</span> based on <code>&lt;html&gt;</code> font-size</li>
          <li><span class="css-units">%</span> based on parent font size</li>
          <li><span class="css-units">vh</span> (viewport height) based on screen height</li>
          <li><span class="css-units">vw</span> (viewport width) based on screen width</li>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <aside class="news">
        <h2>Not a news</h2>
        <p>A web page should look good on any device!</p>
      </aside>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer">Welcome to the responsive world!</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```